# Setting delegate for custom protocol interferes with UIScrollViewDelegate methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, delegates, protocols

I'm using a custom subclass of `UIScrollView` called `ImageScrollView`. I need to know when the user taps the scroll view, so I created a protocol. I implement the protocol in my `RootViewController` and everything looks ok. When I build it, theres a warning

> Class 'ImageScrollView' does not implement the 'TapDetectingImageViewDelegate' protocol".

After inspecting the `init` method in the `ImageScrollView` class, I see that `self.delegate = self;` is causing the problem. I declare myself the delegate for the `UIScrollView` delegate methods, but I also am the delegate for my own protocol (Delegate for my protocol must be `RootViewController`, not `ImageScrollView`).

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
      if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
         self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
         self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
         self.bouncesZoom = YES;
         self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
         self.delegate = self;        
      }
      return self;
 }
```

Do you guys know how can I solve that? Or a better idea to tell my `RootViewController` that user has tapped the `UIScrollView`/`UIImage`.

**Declaration of protocol in ImageScrollView.h**

```
@protocol TapDetectingImageViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)tapDetectingImageView:(ImageScrollView *)view gotSingleTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint;

@end
```

**Header file of class that implements it**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ImageScrollView.h"

@interface AppleScrollViewViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, TapDetectingImageViewDelegate>{

    UIScrollView *pagingScrollView;
}

-(void)configurePage:(ImageScrollView *)page forIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (CGRect)frameForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (CGRect)frameForPagingScrollView;
- (UIImage *)imageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (NSString *)imageNameAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (CGSize)imageSizeAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (NSArray *)imageData;

@end
```

**Protocol method in .m class that implements it**

```
-(void)tapDetectingImageView:(ImageScrollView *)view gotSingleTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint{
    NSLog(@"SingleTap");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration of your protocol and the .h for the class that implements the protocol? It sounds like the signature of the method declaration in the protocol and the implementation don't match.

Comment: While I was posting the stuff you asked, noticed I was implementing the wrong protocol method in my class. I implemented the right method and it logs "Single Tap". But Im still getting the warning. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the view controller to be its delegate, then don't set the delegate within the initializer. When you're creating the `ImageScrollView` instance, you should set it to the view controller.

```
ImageScrollView * aScrollView = [[ImageScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
aScrollView.delegate = self;
[..]
```

If you are creating it this via IB i.e. renaming the class name of a `UIScrollView` to `ImageScrollView`, you will have to create an outlet for it and then set the delegate in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller.

However, there is an issue with this approach. If `ImageScrollView` is the subclass of a `UIScrollView` as the name suggests, the `delegate` property of the scroll view is lost. You should take that into consideration as well.

Comment: This is where I am now. My protocol works now, but the delegate property of the scrollview is lost. Do you know any workaround or hint?

Comment: What do you mean it is lost? How are you initializing the object? How are you setting the delegate?

Comment: All the config/appearance I made in ImageScrollView class via its delegate methods (UIScrollView delegate method ones, since ImageScrollView is a subclass of UIScrollView) no longer works. Seems like if my protocol does work, the UIScrollView ones doesn't.

Comment: Declare your protocol like this `@protocol TapDetectingImageViewDelegate <UIScrollViewDelegate>`.

Comment: Didn't work. I did some tests and found that If my protocol is working, the UIScrollView one didn't work. And the other way around. This may sound stupid, but do u know if there is a way to tell, for example, ImageScrollView wants to be the delegate for UIScrollView protocols ONLY? This drives me crazy now..

Comment: In such case rename the `delegate` property in your `ImageScrollView` class to something like `imageScrollViewDelegate`. This way you can create the distinction. It is ok for delegate variables not to be named `delegate`. There are several such instances within Apple's frameworks

Comment: Nice. It worked like a charm. Thank you, I really appreciate that! I always thought "delegate" was a must variable name. You can give it the name you want as long as you remember its type. Now I see Jhaliya's advise. Again, thank you mate!

Answer (score 1):

You will be having an declaration of `RootViewController` delegate in the **.h** file of `ImageScrollView`,

Change the name of root delegate to `rootDelegate` ;

**In ImageScrollView.h**

```
  RootViewControllerDelegate* rootDelegate;
  @property(nonatomic,assign) RootViewControllerDelegate* rootDelegate;
```

**in ImageScrollView.m file**

```
@synthesize rootDelegate;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
      if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
         self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
         self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
         self.bouncesZoom = YES;
         self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
         self.delegate = self;    
         // Root controller delegate.
         self.rootDelegate = self;            
      }
      return self;
 }
```

Comment: The problem im having is that ImageScrollView declares the protocol, and with the "self.delegate = self" assumes itself must implement the protocol as well which is totally wrong. ImageScrollView declares the protocol and my 'RootViewController' must implements it. That's why xcode throws the warning in ImageScrollView. Any idea?